# Servlet Configuration on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I developed a WebApplication using Netbeans and Glassfish server. I wanted to deploy that on the Tomcat server.But I was not able to run the servlet on Tomcat. I did the following

1. Created a folder "fti" inside ROOT directory of Tomcat
2. Placed index.jsp inside fti directory which I was able to access through my browser
3. I created WEB-INF folder inside "fti" folder and put web.xml file inside it.
4. I created classes folder inside "WEB-INF" folder and put the compiled java file test.class inside it.
5. I tried calling the servlet through the browser by trying to access /fti/test and got the error as "The requested resource (/fti/test) is not available."

I was able to run the same servlet using the same web.xml file with Netbeans and glassfish server

My `test.java` file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class test extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet test</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet test </h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}

}
```

My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: in step 4, are you placing manually .class files into classes folder ?

Comment: are you sure your code compiles successfully without this error:  `try` without `catch`, `finally` or resource declarations

Comment: Why on earth aren't you using an IDE? It will automate many of these steps for you and ensure everything is in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the "ROOT" webapp with a top-level document directory. `fti` would need to be a sibling of ROOT to behave as you're expecting, not a child.

Answer (score 1):

A servlet, or any REST request path, is not simply a remote filesystem.  In your `web.xml` you've told your container that the servlet's name is `test` and that its path is `test/`, so try calling `test` instead of `fti/test`.

Comment: "The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the request object minus the context path and the path parameters." So the context-path `fti` has to be there...

Answer (score 0):

The folder `fti` should be under the folder `webapps` that you can find in the same folder where Tomcat is installed. In addition the class `test.class` should be in `webapps/fti/WEB_INF/classes`. You should be able to access it via `/fti/test`